# R - Selenium endlessly loads webpage

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

I've been successfully running a script daily for a while, but now it seems to be throwing a timeout error.

```
chromever = "96.0.4664.45"

rD <-  rsDriver(browser="chrome", port= free_port(), chromever = chromever)

remDr <- rD[["client"]]
  
remDr$navigate("https://www.theweathernetwork.com/ca/14-day-weather-trend/british-columbia/coquitlam")
  
pageinfo <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
  
precipitation <- pageinfo %>% html_nodes(".wxCell .wxObs") %>% html_text()
```

On the navigate line, the webpage endlessly loads, eventually throwing the following error:

```
Selenium message:timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 299.608
  (Session info: chrome=96.0.4664.45)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-2', revision: 'f148142cf8', time: '2019-07-01T21:30:10'
System info: host: 'WSS-WEATHER', ip: '*my ip here*', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_291'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Error:   Summary: Timeout
     Detail: An operation did not complete before its timeout expired.
     class: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

Chrome hasn't updated or anything, so I'm not sure what may have caused this to start happening seemingly out of the blue. Any ideas?

Comment: Worked fine for me. May be due to slow internet connection? or else try firefox.

Comment: Bizarre. It wasn't working for 6 days and has now fixed itself.....